# How to deserialize OffsetDateTime in Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am not able to deserialize `OffsetDateTime` in spring data elasticsearch when I am simply getting document from the cluster. There are some approaches how to solve the issue, but mostly valid for the previous versions of Spring boot. As well in the current snapshot release of spring-data-elasticsearch the jackson mapper is removed and replaced by some mapper class.

May somebody please give me a hint how to solve this properly with current version of boot + elastic 6.x/7.x ?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I am using REST High level client.

**Solution:**
Solved with custom entity mapper:

```
public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CustomEntityMapper() {

            JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
            javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new MillisOrLocalDateTimeDeserializer());

            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                                      .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                                      .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                                     .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
                                      .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                                      .registerModule(javaTimeModule)
            ;

            objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

            objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    }

    @Override
    public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapObject(Object source) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T readObject(Map<String, Object> source, Class<T> targetType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2 you will need to use a customized Jackson Mapper where you register corresponding modules.

From Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 on (currently available as milestone release 4.0.0.M3) `OffsetDateTime` can be written and read with a custom date format, it seems that `OffsetDateTime` is picky with parsing, I would have thought that the *basic_date_time* format should work, but I had to find a custom format string.

I just tried the following definition:

```
@Field(type=FieldType.Date, format=DateFormat.custom, pattern="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZ")
```

But as said, this would be for the upcoming version 4 of Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thing is, I was not able to find any example of customized jackson mapper working with `RestHighLevelClient`, because the bean ElasticsearchTeamplate where mapper is to be injected, needs just `Client` class, which is deprecated TransportClient. As well, I cannot just register the time modules with global Jackson bean, because spring data elasticsearch is using its own bean..

Comment: I figured it somehow, I am just curious, how to save the time+timezone in `@Field(type=Date)` without implementing the customized mapper. Is it possible?

Comment: not in Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2. From version 4.0 on this will be working as I wrote out of the box. I thought about adding something to be able to use the name of a predefined DateTimeFormatter in the pattern attribute of the Field annotation; this would work for converting the entity, but the pattern itself is needed for writing the indexmapping and DateTimeFormatter has no method to reveal the pattern that should be used.

Comment: The problems you have with customizing the mapper and that users have to add all this stuff in their custom mapping is btw one of the reasons why we do not use the Jackson mapper in the coming version

Answer (score 0):

You can use this annotation.

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_optional_time)
```

I found it on this link.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html